# How to run .py file in PyCharm from command prompt

Tags: python, command-line, pycharm

I'm trying to create a batch file which will run a .py file using PyCharm. What command lines do I use to do such?

I am able to open the .py file in PyCharm via Command Prompt, but I can't seem to find how to run the file.

```
cd [pycharm directory]
pycharm64.exe [example.py]
```

These two lines open up example.py in PyCharm. How do I instead make example.py run?

Comment: You run the file with `python example.py`. PyCharm is an IDE

Comment: Thank you. Now that I've done that, none of the libraries I had installed for PyCharm are installed for the executable. Is there a way to download all of those libraries again?

Comment: If you have your project under a virtual environment you should first activate it

Comment: Excellent, it works perfectly! Thank you!